# changing look and feel doesn't apply to jfilechooser when using spring boot

Tags: java, spring, swing, spring-boot, jfilechooser

I am creating a **swing** application with using **spring boot**. and the frame that i try to use is registered as a component in the application context.

```
    @Bean
    public UploadForm createUploadForm(){
        return new UploadForm();
    }
```

this is how i started the application at first

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        SpringApplicationBuilder springApplicationBuilder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class);
        springApplicationBuilder.headless(false);
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = springApplicationBuilder.run(args);
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            UploadForm uploadForm = context.getBean(UploadForm.class);
            uploadForm.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
```

but with this way file chooser appear in the same old way. but if we use **new** **UploadForm** instead of the **registered bean** in the **context** everything looks fine, **jfilechooser** appear in the windows look and feel format

```
     UploadForm uploadForm = new UploadForm();
     uploadForm.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the look and feel before the bean is constructed. Try to move the line `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());` before context creation.